I want to understand how an api gateway should behave in general
I want to understand how an api gateway should behave in general if it has got a path param like a%2Fv. Should it pass to the upstream as it is ? Or should it encode it to a%252Fv and then pass to upstream ?
Need help to understand the behavior.
